# Help with De Moivre's Theorem: Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a homework problem which goes:

Given $z^n=(z+i)^n$, using de Moivre's Theorem,
show that

$z=\frac{i}{e^\frac{i2k\pi}{n}-1}$

What steps should I take in tackling this question? It's a 2 mark question and I 
can't seem to find an appropriate way to solve it quickly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

First prove that $z \ne 0$ and then divide both sides of the equation by $z^n$. Then note that $\frac{z+i}{z} = 1 + \frac{i}{z}$.

Comment: Hi, sorry but what do I do to prove the value of z after that? Thanks

Comment: @SheowBoon: Well, first tell me what you get after that. Math SE is not here to do your homework for you, but to guide you to solve problems by yourself as far as possible.

Comment: What I get is i/z=0, so I could then derive that z=i/0, but I'm not sure why z would equal to infinity, if it still is a complex number.

Comment: @SheowBoon: Show how you get $\frac{i}{z} = 0$. That's not possible.

Comment: @SheowBoon: Ah I know your mistake. $(?)^n = 1$ does not imply $? = 1$.

Comment: @SheowBoon: And by the way the question is wrong. $k$ cannot be any arbitrary integer; it must not be a multiple of $n$.

Comment: Hmm, so far, what I've got is: $z^n=(z+i)^n$, 1=1+$frac\{i}{z}$, and that's how I got i/z=0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41409/discussion-between-sheow-boon-and-user21820).

Answer (score 1):

Take $z^n$ common from Rhs cancelling $z^n$ as $|z|\neq 0$ we get $(1+\frac{i}{z})^n=1$ now let $(1+..)=l$ so we get $l^n=1$ thus $l=e^{\frac{i2k\pi}{n}}$ so $z=..$  we get the desired result